# Adding data using C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle, odp.net

My goal is to add data to Oracle database. I've tried the tutorial at this link(https://youtu.be/LUKp76CNmJY) which is helpful for beginner. But the INSERT does not work(DELETE also does not work). However UPDATE works. Typical HR account is used. Do I specify some sort privillege to the app.config? I have no idea.(UPDATE works, which means success connection and the updating is granted to HR.)

Part of code as below.

**app.config**

```
...
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=ORCL;PASSWORD=Oracle11;USER ID=HR"
            providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
    </connectionStrings>
...
```

**CS file**

```
...
        private void updateDataGrid()  //SELECT statement isuued.
        {
            OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,LAST_NAME,JOB_ID,HIRE_DATE,EMAIL FROM EMPLOYEES";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            myDataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            dr.Close();
        }
        private void setConnection() //Getting connection.
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            con = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
            try
            { con.Open(); } catch (Exception exp) { }
        }
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {   this.updateDataGrid();  }

...


        private void add_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  //Event listner. 
        {
            string sql = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES(EMPLOYEE_ID,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID)" +
                "VALUES(:EMPLOYEE_ID,:LAST_NAME,:EMAIL,:HIRE_DATE,:JOB_ID)";
            this.AUD(sql, 0);
            ...
        }

      
...
        private void AUD(string sql_stmt, int state)  // Making Oracle statement string
        {
            string msg = "";
            OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = sql_stmt;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            switch (state)
            {
                case 0:
                    msg = "Row Inserted Successfully!";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("EMPLOYEE_ID", OracleDbType.Int32, 6).Value = Int32.Parse(employee_id_txtbx.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("LAST_NAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 25).Value = last_name_txtbx.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("EMAIL", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 25).Value = email_txtbx.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("HIRE_DATE", OracleDbType.Date, 7).Value = hire_date_picker.SelectedDate;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("JOB_ID", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 10).Value = job_id_txtbx.Text;
                    break;
               ...
            }
            try
            {
                int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (n > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(msg);
                    this.updateDataGrid();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception expe) { };
        }

 ...
```

Comment: Seems like string concatenation on the `INSERT` statement probably has `VALUES` right after the bracket, use verbatim strings for multiline queries `var sql = @"..."`

Answer (score -2):

I didn't get the schema of HR. The JOB_ID column is FK. Therefore, when inputted to textbox at JOB_ID, JOB_ID SHOULD NOT inputted arbitarily.
For instance,
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES(EMPLOYEE_ID, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, HIRE_DATE, JOB_ID) VALUES(90, 'ss', 'sss','2020-10-09', 'sssss');  -- NO!
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES(EMPLOYEE_ID, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, HIRE_DATE, JOB_ID) VALUES(90, 'ss', 'sss','2020-10-09', 'AD_PRES'); --OK